# Designing gumy service relational database

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I'm working on a small school project. I'm struggling with connecting the tables of DB (more specifically schedule - get all the info and connecting box, storage, and tires that are mentioned in the contract - i put aggregation). Here is a pic of my solution: https://ibb.co/eV1D8b . Does it look ok?

The task goes:

The company has more business office across the country. In addition to tire assembly, there are still several services: sales (tires and other products), tire maintenance, etc...
To change tires at the beginning of the season, it is necessary to order it by phone. The operator receives a call and for each box where it is possible to change the tires, see the booking records. Changing the tire takes 30 min.
Upon arrival, the user arrives at the counter where based on registration of the vehicle a work order is made for the employee in the box (on which the number of tire code contracts was recorded). The tires are then transported from warehouse to the box for the assembly. When the tires are stored, a contract is signed to ensure that after a contracted deadline of 6 months tires are kept for another 60 days, which is paid annually by $ 0.10 per tire daily. The price of tire storage depends on the size and is calculated per piece.
There is a possibility of joining the Loyalty Club and getting discounts for all family cars. The discount is valid only for services, not for products.
With companies that want the services of this tire service (rent-a-car, utility vehicles, etc...), a contract will be concluded to provide a more affordable price for tire assembly and storage.

Comment: Please ask a specific question about something you are not sure about given some stuff you are sure about, quoting only relevant spec parts. Please read & act on hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. Use edit functions to inline, not link, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained. Also reference the specific design method & ERD style you are using, there are many.

Comment: PS What is your question?